# DHCP Reservation - Linksys E2500 - Advanced Tomato in Wireless Ethernet Bridge Mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm running Advanced Tomato on an old Linksys E2500. I've managed to set it up as a Wireless Ethernet Bridge.

On my host/primary router I see the IP address it's assigned to the tomato router. I plugged an old laptop into the bridge's ethernet port and it's online. I also plugged my networked printer into the bridge and accessed it from a different machine using the tomato router's ip address.

My problem is that my host router only ever assigns an ip address to the tomato router, but I have the printer and a media server that need their own addresses--in my previous setup I had reserved ip addresses for them on the host router.

As I understood it, having advanced tomato in wireless ethernet bridge modes allows the host router to handle dhcp for any device connected to the bridge. I thought that'd mean that each device would receive a distinct ip address. Am I wrong to think this?

Ideally my host router would see the mac addresses of each device connected to the bridge, which is what happened when I was using a simple wired network hub. Is there something I should/could configure Advanced Tomato's advanced network settings to make this happen?

Thanks for any help/advice.

-JL

Comment: The host AP is the main router in a TP-Link Deco mesh network. Limited admin features on both the cloud interface and connecting via the router's IP unfortunately.

Comment: You should have a DHCP forwarding option, it should be set to the main router to relay the DHCP requests. The second router should not be assigned it's admin IP through DHCP, it should be set statically.